# How to correctly change line character limit configuration in PHP CodeSniffer?

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer

So I want to change the values for `$lineLimit` and `$absoluteLineLimit` that PHP CodeSniffer uses when checking files. After some googling I tried to make my own standard to facilitate this but I haven't got it working. Working on Ubuntu 12.04.4LTS and in the system directory for PHP CodeSniffer I put in my folder `MyStandard` and in the subdirectory `Sniffs` I have what is to be my personal Sniff to change the line limit called `LineLimit120Sniff.php`

The code is as follows

```
class LineLimit120Sniff extends Generic_Sniffs_Files_LineLengthSniff
{
    public $lineLimit = 100;
    public $absoluteLineLimit = 120;
}
```

When I try to run `phpcs --standard=MyStandard <file>` I get the this as output

> PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 3 in /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer.php
>   on line 1189
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class
>   LineLimit120Sniff in
>   /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/Standards/MyStandard/Sniffs/LineLimit120Sniff.php
>   on line 8

I don't understand, how is the class being redeclared..? What am I doing wrong? Or alternatively, is there an easier way to change the `$lineLimit` setting?

Comment: `cd /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer && grep -r "class LineLimit120Sniff" .`. Are there more than one defined?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easy way is just create a ruleset.xml in a location you like and insert the text below into it.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="MyStandard">
    <description>This standard changes the line length</description>

    <!-- Insert all sniff from PSR2 standard -->
    <rule ref="PSR2"/>

    <rule ref="Generic.Files.LineLength">
        <properties>
            <property name="lineLimit" value="100"/>
            <property name="absoluteLineLimit" value="120"/>
        </properties>
     </rule>
</ruleset>
```

Use the standard by

```
phpcs --standard=/path/to/ruleset.xml test.php
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this! :) It's for work though so I probably won't get around to it till Monday but ah well. Is there a way to make my ruleset extend that of a preinstalled standard (e.g. PSR2) without just copy-pasting from the existing standard?

Comment: I updated my answer. You can refer to any standard or even to sniffs from standards inside your own ruleset.xml. You should be aware of sniffs which interfere with each other. For example if the PSR2 standard contains also a sniffs which checks for line length you should override that instead of the one from Generic standard.